# Load value from popup to InventoryID field

Tags: acumatica

am generating a pop on one new button click in stock Items screen, inside popup have two buttons, user select some data from fields in the popup and then click on ok, then inventoryId should be formed with some special characters and then it should display in InventoryID field. I can form the InventoryID but unable to display it in InventoryID field.

```
    [PXButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Generate")]
    public virtual void GenerateInv()
    {
        InventoryItemExt ext = Base.Item.Cache.GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>(Base.Item.Current);

        Base.Item.Current.InventoryCD = ext.UsrInvId;
        Base.Item.Cache.Insert(Base.Item.Current);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue before,
and the following code was provided by acumatica. you may try the same.
here in the below code, inventoryCD contains the value, i wanted to set.

```
  InventoryItem item = PXCache<InventoryItem>.CreateCopy(Base.Item.Current);

  OrderedDictionary keys = new OrderedDictionary(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
                {
                    {
                        typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD).Name, 
                        adapter.View.Cache.GetValue(adapter.View.Cache.Current, 
                        typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD).Name)
                    }
                };
                    OrderedDictionary vals = new OrderedDictionary(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
                { 
                    { 
                        typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD).Name, inventoryCD 
                    } 
                };
                    adapter.View.Cache.Update(keys, vals);
                    if (adapter.Searches != null && adapter.Searches.Length > 0)
                    {
                        adapter.Searches[0] = inventoryCD;
                        }    
  return adapter.Get();
```

Also make sure your function have the correct input and the return type

```
 IEnumerable GenerateInv(PXAdapter adapter)
```

Comment: Thanks Hybridzz, with the above code and am able to set the value in InventoryID field but the default behavior of Acumatica is not working like, after the InventoryID is set and when am selecting Item Class, Item Class changes pop up is firing and asking for confirmation message. This happens only when we are changing Item class for already created item. Please help me how can i solve it.

Comment: you may accept the answer for your current question and post your new question with your code. so it will be more clear what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hybridzz, i accepted as answer and posted as new question, "Loading popup value to InventoryID field
"